# Finding UMVUE for uniform distribution $U(\alpha, \beta)$

Tags: statistics, estimation

Let $X = (X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$ be a sample from uniform distribution $U(\alpha, \beta): \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}, \alpha < \beta$.  I have to find UMVUE for the parameters $\alpha, \beta$.

Using factorization theorem I showed that $T(X) = (\min\{ X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_2\}, \max\{ X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n \})$ is a sufficient statistic.

I think that I should use [Lehmann–Scheffé theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmann%E2%80%93Scheff%C3%A9_theorem). Should I solve this problem by fixing $\beta$ and then computing the UMVUE for $\alpha$? Then vive versa?

I tried to find an unbiased estimator for $\alpha$ first. Thinking of $\beta$ as fixed I found that
$$\mathbb{E}(2X_1 - \beta) =  \alpha.$$
Thus using Lehmann–Scheffé theorem UMVUE would be
$$\mathbb{E}(2X_1 - \beta|T(X)).$$
How can I find conditional expected value when $T(X)$ is a vector?

On the other hand I fixed $\beta$ in order to find my unbiased estimator so should I calculate $\mathbb{E}(2X_1 - \beta|X_{(1)})$?

I am a bit confused. I would appreciate any hints or tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T=(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ is not only sufficient but a *complete* sufficient statistic which is needed here, $X_{(k)}$ being the $k$th $\,(1\le k\le n)$ order statistic.

Since the $X_i$'s are i.i.d $U(a,b)$ variables, $Y_i=\frac{X_i-a}{b-a}$ are i.i.d $U(0,1)$ variables, $\, 1\le i\le n$.

Now it is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_a_uniform_distribution) that $Y_{(1)}\sim \text{Beta}(1,n)$ and $Y_{(n)}\sim\text{Beta}(n,1)$, implying $E(Y_{(1)})=\frac{1}{n+1}$ and $E(Y_{(n)})=\frac{n}{n+1}$. So all you have to do is solve for $a$ and $b$ from the equations

$$E(X_{(1)})=\frac{b-a}{n+1}+a\\ E(X_{(n)})=\frac{(b-a)n}{n+1}+a$$

You would get $a$ and $b$ as unbiased estimators of some function of $T$, and those will be the corresponding UMVUEs by Lehmann-Scheffe theorem.

Comment: Does that mean that my UMVUE will be a vector too?

Comment: @Hendrra No, the UMVUEs are linear combinations of $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(n)}$.

Comment: One for b and one for a?

Comment: I would like to as what does the fact that $T$ is also a complete statistics change? My guess is that is is linked to the conditional expected value, am I right?

Comment: @Hendrra Lehmann-Scheffe theorem applies to complete sufficient statistics.

Comment: I thought that this theorem says that if $T(X)$ is a sufficient statistics and $W(X)$ is any unbiased estimator then $\mathbb{E}(W(X) | T(X)$ is UMVUE. Maybe there are several ways to express this theorem.

Comment: @Hendrra No, $T$ must be complete and sufficient.

Comment: Then $\mathbb{E}(W(X) | T(X)$ is UMVUE? After finding a and b as linear combinations of $X_(1)$ and $X_(n)$ am I to compute the conditional expected value?]

Comment: @Hendrra If you have found an unbiased estimator of your parameter based on a complete sufficient statistic, then that is bound to be the UMVUE and it equals the conditional expectation ( the latter is sometimes difficult to compute). This follows from Lehmann-Scheffe.

Comment: Thank you! Now I think I understand. For any linear combination of a complete sufficient statistics I would have (it's very simplified here) $\mathbb{E}(cT(X) | T(X)) = cT(X)$. If I had any unbiased estimator I would have to compute the conditional expectation step by step.

Comment: @Hendrra The linear combination part is irrelevant (it's only here that the UMVUEs are linear combinations, not in general).

Comment: I understand! Thank you for your time and help :)

Comment: How can we show that it's complete?

Comment: @Tapi https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/225580/119261